# Привязка костей к отдельному объекту (Ragdoll)

Tags: unity3d

Можно ли как-то привязать, скажем руки ragdoll-а к какому то объекту или вектору так, чтобы они были привязаны к отдельному объекту, а остальные кости вели себя как полагается ragdoll-у?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Да, в Unity вы можете привязать определенные части Ragdoll к другим объектам или векторам. Для этого вы можете использовать различные техники, такие как привязка к скриптам, динамическое изменение констрейнтов или использование физических сил.

Одним из способов сделать это является использование физических констрейнтов, таких как ConfigurableJoint. Вы можете создать ConfigurableJoint для руки Ragdoll и привязать его к другому объекту или вектору. Это позволит руке Ragdoll следовать за указанным объектом или вектором, в то время как остальные части Ragdoll будут вести себя как обычно.

Вот пример кода, который вы могли бы использовать для привязки руки Ragdoll к объекту в Unity:

```cs
using UnityEngine;

public class AttachRagdollPart : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform targetObject; // Объект, к которому вы хотите привязать руку Ragdoll

    void Start()
    {
        ConfigurableJoint joint = gameObject.AddComponent<ConfigurableJoint>();
        joint.connectedBody = targetObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        // Настройте другие параметры констрейнта по вашему усмотрению
    }
}
```

Прикрепите этот скрипт к руке Ragdoll в вашем проекте Unity, и это заставит руку игнорировать физические силы, сохраняя её в нужном положении.

---

Второй вариант - вы можете закрепить руку Ragdoll так, чтобы на неё не действовали физические силы. Для этого вы можете использовать методы управления физическим поведением объекта, такие как установка его физического тела (Rigidbody) в состояние isKinematic или изменение его массы и других параметров.

Вот пример того, как вы можете сделать руку Ragdoll невосприимчивой к физическим силам в Unity:

```cs
using UnityEngine;

public class FreezeRagdollPart : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        Rigidbody rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        if (rb != null)
        {
            rb.isKinematic = true; // Устанавливаем физическое тело в состояние isKinematic, чтобы объект не реагировал на физические силы
        }
    }
}
```

Прикрепите этот скрипт к руке Ragdoll в вашем проекте Unity, и это заставит руку игнорировать физические силы, сохраняя её в нужном положении.

Далее вы можете переместить руку в требуемое вам положение на сцене через transform.position.

Comment: Спасибо большое!